# What is the naming procedure for rocks on Mars?

Tags: mars, terminology

I *think* that the relevant naming 'authority' for e.g. *craters* on the Moon (and Mars) is the [International Astronomical Union](http://www.iau.org). Besides weak spots in the system, the basic idea is that people or institutions can *propose* names for a crater. This is usually done for paying respect and honour to important and/or deceased members of the space exploration and astronomy communities. Notable examples are the [Tsiolkovskiy crater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovskiy_%28crater%29) (after [Konstantin Tsiolkovsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky)) or a group of seven lunar craters named after the crew of [STS-51-L](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=5v8lAAAAIBAJ&sjid=Q_wFAAAAIBAJ&pg=4112,2485024).

I have observed that the teams of e.g. the Mars Exploration Rovers and Mars Science Lab also give names to a lot of objects, rocks and mountains etc along their routes. Those names are then used in (scientific) literature, too. **What are the official procedures for naming such objects, if there are any?** Do they accept proposals (from non-team-members) and/or are there examples of this happening in the past?

*As odd as this question may be, it is relevant with respect to 'exploration'. The first thing humans do, if they discover something new, is giving names.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rocks_on_Mars)

> Names for Mars rocks are
>   largely unofficial designations
>   used for ease of discussion
>   purposes, as the International
>   Astronomical Union 's official
>   Martian naming system
>   declares that objects smaller
>   than 100 m (330 ft) are not
>   to be given official names.
>   Because of this some less
>   significant rocks seen in
>   photos returned by Mars
>   rovers have been named more
>   than once, and others have
>   even had their names changed
>   later due to conflicts or even
>   matters of opinion. Often
>   rocks are named after the
>   children or family members of
>   astronauts or NASA employees.

HOW DO THEY APPROVE THE [NAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nomenclature) :

> When images are first
>   obtained of the surface of a
>   planet or satellite, a theme for
>   naming features is chosen and
>   a few important features are
>   named, usually by members of
>   the appropriate IAU task
>   group (a commonly accepted
>   planet-naming group). Later,
>   as higher resolution images
>   and maps become available,
>   additional features are named
>   at the request of
>   investigators mapping or
>   describing specific surfaces,
>   features, or geologic
>   formations. Anyone may
>   suggest that a specific name
>   be considered by a task group.
>   If the members of the task
>   group agree that the name is
>   appropriate, it can be retained
>   for use when there is a
>   request from a member of the
>   scientific community that a
>   specific feature be named.
>   Names successfully reviewed by
>   a task group are submitted to
>   the IAU Working Group for
>   Planetary System
>   Nomenclature (WGPSN). Upon
>   successful review by the
>   members of the WGPSN, names
>   are considered provisionally
>   approved and can be used on
>   maps and in publications as
>   long as the provisional status is
>   clearly stated. Provisional
>   names are then presented for
>   adoption to the IAU's General
>   Assembly, which met triennially
>   in the past, and which now
>   adopts nomenclature for
>   planetary surface features as
>   required. A name is not
>   considered to be official —
>   that is, "adopted" — until the
>   General Assembly has given its
>   approval.